# Send an SMS message (UTF-16) with an unknown character replaced by a "replacement character" in Android

Tags: android, unicode, sms, gsm, utf-16

I have a problem with sending SMS messages. I created a string with characters like "\uFDE8" (it's 65000). When I convert it back, I get 65000. It looks OK.

But when I send an SMS with this string and receive the message, I have this character replaced with "\uFFFD" (65533). This character is called a "replacement character".

Why was my character replaced?

//edit 
My solution is to convert each char of string to 7-bit and then send it. You must notice that gms alphabet is different from ascii (some chars needs to be replace to another). Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

According to the Unicode table, `U+FDE8` is not a valid codepoint.

As you would expect, any invalid character gets replaced by your provider's SMS system by [`U+FFFD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` �, which in itself is a valid Unicode character, but only exists to show that the original one cannot be properly represented.

Comment: The code point is valid, but unassigned, i.e. no character is assigned to it (so far).

Comment: According to Unicode 6.1 [chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFB50.pdf), `U+FDE8` is non-character. *These codes are permitted for process-internal uses, but are not permitted for interchange*.